# Missing scripts in NMAP

Tags: nmap

I've just installed the latest Kali and updated everything. `nmap` is version 7.12.

I've noticed that `smb-check-vulns.nse` is not present. As far as I can tell, most other scripts I use are there but I've got an exam coming up and I don't want any bad surprises.

I tried to manually add `smb-check-vulns.nse` by fetching the script source from nmap.org, but that gave me some errors and the script is not running.

Was there a change that deprecated some scripts recently, or am I the only one experiencing a missing script? Is there any way to ensure I have all `nmap` scripts installed?

Comment: Did you run `nmap --script-updatedb' like the documentation suggests?

Comment: @atdre I did but that doesn't seem to have added any scripts it didn't already have. I have a lot of the scripts, but I seem to be missing a few key ones. It didn't give me `smb-check-vulns`.

Comment: https://nmap.org/nsedoc/categories/vuln.html lists the active scripts. It also shows the replacements to `smb-check-vulns`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [changelog for Nmap 6.49BETA6](https://nmap.org/changelog.html#6.49BETA6) says:

> [GH#171] smb-check-vulns has been split into:
>
> ```
>     smb-vuln-conficker
>     smb-vuln-cve2009-3103
>     smb-vuln-ms06-025
>     smb-vuln-ms07-029
>     smb-vuln-regsvc-dos
>     smb-vuln-ms08-067
> ```
>
> The scripts now use the vulns library, and the "unsafe" script-arg has been replaced by putting the scripts into the "dos" category. [Paulino Calderon]

Answer (score 9):

Basically just run `--script vuln` instead of `--script smb-check-vulns`

and you will get your results.

In the latest NMAP versions "vuln" is a category that has all vulnerabilities in them instead of a separate smb-check-vulns command.

Answer (score 3):

Lisen to Paulino Calderon (we have develop many nse scripts to nmap).

See this video here showing how to port nse scripts and libs
to nmap database: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARuIQDDXrBg

you can use script 'categories' to run all scripts inside that
categorie, example: nmap --script dos (will run all scripts
inside categorie dos) https://nmap.org/nsedoc/

About --script-updatedb switch ...
it DOES NOT retrieve anything from network (updates), that switch
serves to manually update nmap database if you are locally developing
nse scripts or libs to nmap ...

Comment: You may be answering the question, but your answer is very confusing.  You add a link and then assume that people would perfectly understand what is in the video, link die, therefore it is much better to add a summary here.  Moreover, you then say that updatedb does not retrieve anything from the network but does something locally.  Yet, you do not provide an example of either.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use the following command to check all specific vulnerabilities for SMB

```
 nmap -p445 --script smb-vuln-* <target>
```